# Prevent access to a folder based on roles

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a sub folder called admin. I want to protect it to users with roles ADMIN only. How do I do that. I have created a new web.config and put that within that folder. Following is my web config.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="ADMIN"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But all the authenticated users are being able to access that. How do I protect that folder contents.

**EDIT**

The authentication is done in parent folder and the same login is being used for user and admin.

Comment: Have you tried with `<deny users="*"/>` after `<allow roles="ADMIN"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="ADMIN"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```